# whosmat Attribute error in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a .mat file and I want to list variables of this file:

```
import scipy.io as sio 
import numpy as np
mat_contents = sio.loadmat('dga.mat') #read the .mat file
mat_variables = sio.whosmat('dga.mat') #list the variables
```

I tried it with scipy.io.whosmat, however I am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dga_data.py", line 6, in <module>
    mat_variables = sio.whosmat('dga.mat')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'whosmat'
```

I have had no problem with scipy.io.loadmat and scipy.io.savemat for reading and saving the file. Does anoyone know why it crashes for scipy.io.whosmat?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is new in version 0.12.0.

Possibly you are on an older version, you can check that with `scipy.__version___`.